# Is there any way to deduce city, state, and/or zip code from a phone number in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets list of about 5,000 customers, almost all of which have phone numbers associated. Since many of our customers are from large companies with multiple offices, I'd like to segment as many as possible into their respective office locations. I thought that if  possible to do this easily, it would probably be done using the area code of their work phone number. Does anyone know of a way to use that 3-digit area code to return city/state or zip code in Google Sheets?

Comment: dataset is unknown = unsolvable. share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In addition to the comments above, an area code for a number can only ever tell you the state and, perhaps, the broad region within a state (e.g., Massachusetts North)—not the city or zip code. And with the proliferation of cell phone numbers, the three-digit prefix following an area code can tell you nearly nothing in and of itself. So the best you will ever be able to do with certainty if all the stars aligned is narrow down to a state/region.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create another table that has states and their associated area codes(data can be cut and pasted into your sheet from here: https://www.freshworks.com/freshcaller-cloud-pbx/phone-numbers/us-area-codes/). Then once you have that those two tables you can perform a table merge between your customer table and the area code table(explanation with example here: https://davidmeindl.com/the-ultimate-google-sheets-formula-to-join-two-tables/).